# Return array from php to ajax success

Tags: ajax, arrays, json

I want to return an array from a php function to my ajax call. After that I want to use the array values from the page the ajax call is made.

So this is my ajax call:

```
        $(function() {
        $("#find").click(function() {

            var url = $("#form_url").val();
            var dataString = 'url=' + url;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/add_url.php",
                data: dataString,
                }).done(function( result ) {
                    myresult(result);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });


 function myresult(result) {
var result_lines = result.split("<splitter>");    
if (result_lines[0] == '1') { 
    $('#content_error').html(result_lines[1]).fadeIn(250);
    $('#content_error').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
} else if (result_lines[0] == '2') { 
    $('#content_success').html('Succesfully get images').fadeIn(250);
    $('#url_result').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    $('#content_success').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
    alert(eval(data));
}
return true;
```

}

and this is my php script:

```
 if($_POST['url']) {

    $url = $Db->escape($_POST['url']);

        $html = file_get_html($url);
        $count = 0;
        $goodfiles = array();

        foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {

            $pic = url_to_absolute($url, $element->src);

            if(!empty($pic)){

                $pics = parse_url($pic);
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($pic);

                if($pics["scheme"]=="http" && $width >= 300 && $height >= 250) {

                    array_push($goodfiles,$pic);
                    $_SESSION['pictures'] = $goodfiles;
                    $count++;

                }
            }
      }


        if($count == 0){ 

            $_SESSION['count'] = 'empty'; 
            echo "1<splitter>"; 
            echo "No items found with the correct size"; 


        }else{

            $_SESSION['count'] = $count;
            echo "2<splitter>";
            echo json_encode($_SESSION['pictures']); 

        }

            $_SESSION['url'] = $url;
            $html->clear();
            $empty = 1;
    }

  }
```

when the ajax call is successful I use json_encode on the array to use it on my php page. But I don't know how I get this array to a javascript on the page the ajax call was made of.

right now I'm receiving the following content:

["image.jpeg","image.jpg"]

And I want to put this in a javascript array...

Comment: You should only have one echo in your PHP function

Comment: Firebug shows you the request and the response when an ajax call is made. You might find that very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is this with this line:

```
var result_lines = result.split("<splitter>");
```

`result` (the AJAX response) is an object or array (depending on the nature of your JSON) but you are trying to call a string method (`split()`) on it.

This would cause an error in your JS console - *always check the console*.

Finally, `eval()` is evil and almost never required except in exceptional circumstances. Try to avoid it.

Comment: The splitter is to determine an error (splitter 1) or a successful call (splitter 2). You can call the results by using the function result lines. So calling the json_encode echo can be done by using $('#id').html(result_lines[1]).... But is html the right way?! And how do I place the array in a javascript then?!

Comment: Not sure I follow. The fact remains `result` is an object or array, neither of which has a method `split()`. Are you saying `result` is NOT an object or array, but is coming back as a string? jQuery normally identifies JSON responses and parses it as such. You can enforce this by adding a param to your AJAX request: `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: If it's an array then my answer stands - arrays have no method `split()`. If it's already an array then you don't need to do anything - it's already usable, e.g. `result[0]` will get the first key of the array. (If you're sure it's an array and not an object).

Comment: I want to put the output of json_encode($test) in a javascript var, so I can use it in a javascript. So for example:

Var images = ["image.jpg", "image.jpg"]

Right now json_encode($test) gives me ["image.jpg", "image.jpg"], so that's oke. Now I need to know how to put this output in the var images. A var doesn't have an id or class, so I don't know how to put it there....

Comment: But you've already got it in a var - `result`. That is the parsed result of what your PHP output.

Comment: got it in a var using var array = result_lines[1];

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work with $.ajax but here is an alternative.

Replace this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/add_url.php",
                data: dataString,
                }).done(function( result ) {
                    myresult(result);
            });
```

with

```
$.post("/ajax/add_url.php",{dataString:dataString},function(data){
           alert(data['you array index']);
},'json')
```

I repeat ,this is my alternative so don't take it hard!

Comment: Why would that change anything?